# Google app engine cron job post?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron the job invokes a get on the specified url. Is there any way to configure a job to invoke a post instead?

Comment: The HTTP GET request can be used to run any script you want, and that script can do a POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the cron job to hit the specific url.  From that `GET` to the url, run a script, and then send a `POST` out to a different url, via the taskqueue:

```
try:
    taskqueue.Task(
       url="/some_url/",
       name=task_name,
       method="POST",
       params={
          "post_param_1": post_param_1,
          "post_param_2": post_param_2,
          "post_param_3": post_param_3,
          etc
       }
   ).add(queue_name="my-queue")
except:
    pass        #throws TombstonedTaskError if tombstoned name used.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about access to this URL, then you can restrict it:

> You can prevent users from accessing URLs used by scheduled tasks by
> restricting access to administrator accounts. Scheduled tasks can
> access admin-only URLs. You can restrict a URL by adding login: admin
> to the handler configuration in app.yaml.
>
> from [Securing URLs for
> cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron#Python_app_yaml_Securing_URLs_for_cron)

Comment: I've already done that for the whole application, since the page contains a button that should be tweeting but I don't want people spamming.